# How to extract the IP part of a variable in bash

Tags: bash

I have written a bash script that reads a text file containing URLs and finds its IP. Each line of this file contains a URL. I want to create a .csv file as output which has 2 columns, the first column for URL and the 2nd column for its IP. Here is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS= read -r line; do
        ip=$(dig +short $line)
        echo "${line}, ${ip}" >> ipfile.csv
done < domains
```

It works fine. The problem is that sometimes when I use `dig +short example.com`, instead of returning only the IP of the "example.com", it returns something like: `example2.com IP`. In this case the 2nd column saves example2.com and the corresponding IP moves to the 1st column of the next row.

So my question is: "How can I ignore the first part (example2.com) and only extract and save the "IP" part in the second column"?

I tried to split the text by space and newline character, but unfortunately it didn't work for me.

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS= read -r line; do
        ip=$(dig +short $line)
        if [[ $ip = *\n* ]]
        then
                bar=${ip##*\n}
                echo "{line}, ${bar}" >> ipfile.csv
        else
                echo "${line}, ${ip}" >> ipfile.csv
        fi 
done < domain
```

Comment: How did you try to split? How did it fail?

Comment: I would use a regular expression https://riptutorial.com/regex/example/14146/match-an-ip-address piped though `grep -P -o <pattern>`. Do you need to accept IP V6 addresses too?

Comment: @mark no I don't

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may extract anything that looks like an IPv4 address using the following grep expression:

```
echo 'hello 11.22.33.44 world' | grep -E -o "[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+"
```

Explanation:

- `-E`: Use regex
- `-o`: Print only the matching part
- `[0-9]+\.`: Match a sequence of digits, followed by a period (escaped because a period in regex has special meaning)

  - This is repeated 4 times, excluding the final period

This solution has some false positives (9999.0000.1.2 passes the pattern) but assuming `dig` doesn't output something seriously messed up, this will do.

Also it doesn't support IPv6, which might be a problem for you, but it is trivial to modify for IPv6 so it is left as an exercise to the reader :)

Comment: I tried this, but for an IP like "127.219.65.10" the output was like this: "7.219.65.10". Suppose we have "example.com. 217.219.65.10", using this code, output was this: "7.219.65.10". What is the reason?

Comment: Edited to fix the bug

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Would you please tell me how I can add the domain ($line) too? The first column contains the domain name and the 2nd one its IP. I tried "echo "$line,  $ip | grep -E -o "[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+"}" >> ipfile.csv", but it didn't work.

Comment: `echo "$line,$(echo "$ip" | grep -E -o "[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+")" >> ipfile.csv`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `dig +shirt` only returns two forms :

```
IP
name IP
```

We can use this script :

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

while IFS= read -r line; do
        read name ip <<<"$(dig +short $line)" # get name and IP
        echo "${line}, ${ip:-$name}" >> ipfile.csv # If second column is absent, take the first column
done < domains
```